# values of p, so that$ f(0)\ge f(1)\ge...\ge f(10)$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $f(x)= {10 \choose x} p^x (1-p)^{10-x} $,$ x=0,1...,10$, zero elsewhere. Find the values of p, so that$ f(0)\ge f(1)\ge...\ge f(10)$. Here is my solution:  $x=0 , {10 \choose 0} p^0 (1-p)^{10-0}; x=1, {10 \choose 1} p^1 (1-p)^{10-1};x=2, {10 \choose 2} p^2 (1-p)^{10-2};...;x=10,{10 \choose 10} p^{10} (1-p)^{10-10};$$x=0$ is $(1-p)^{10};$$x=1 $ is $ 10 p(1-p)^9;$$x=2 $ is $ 45 p^2(1-p)^8;$$x=3$ is $ 120 p^3(1-p)^7;  $ $x=4$ is $ 210p^4(1-p)^6; $$x=5$ is $252  p^5(1-p)^5;$$x=6$ is $210  p^6(1-p)^4;$$x=7$ is $120  p^7(1-p)^3;$$x=8$ is $45  p^8(1-p)^2;$$x=9$ is $10  p^9(1-p);$$x=10$ is $ p^{10};$ Also, $$\sum_{k=o}^{10}f(k)=1$$ How can I find the p? Is there a shortcut to this? Thank you.p

Comment: yes, sorry , i will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $d(k)=f(k)-f(k+1)$. Then

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
d(k) &=& 
\binom{10}{k}p^k(1-p)^{10-k}-\binom{10}{k+1}p^{k+1}(1-p)^{9-k} \\
&=& p^k(1-p)^{9-k}
\left(\binom{10}{k}(1-p)-\binom{10}{k+1}p\right) \\
&=& p^k(1-p)^{9-k}
\left(\frac{10!}{k!(10-k)!}(1-p)-\frac{10!}{(k+1)!(9-k)!}p\right) \\
&=& \frac{10!}{k!(10-k)!} p^k(1-p)^{9-k}
\left((1-p)-\frac{10-k}{k+1}p\right) \\
&=& \binom{10}{k}p^k(1-p)^{9-k}
\left(1-\left(1+\frac{10-k}{k+1}\right)p\right) \\
&=& \binom{10}{k}p^k(1-p)^{9-k}
\left(1-\frac{11p}{k+1}\right) \\
&=& \frac{11}{k+1}\binom{10}{k}p^k(1-p)^{9-k}
\left(\frac{k+1}{11}-p\right) \\
\end{array}
$$

So $d(k)\geq 0$ iff $p \le \frac{k+1}{11}$.
To conclude, your condition is satisfied iff $0\le p \le \frac{1}{11}$.

Comment: is it not iff $0\le p \le \frac{k+1}{11}$?

Comment: @NorbertoVergaraSr. The inequality $p\le \frac{k+1}{11}$ must hold for every $k$ : $k=0,1,2,\ldots,10$. So you have $p\le \frac{0+1}{11}, p\le \frac{1+1}{11}, \ldots$. Combining all those you obtain $p \le \frac{1}{11}$.